# Inkscape: Is there a way to center text in this type of grid?

Tags: inkscape, text, grids

I created a grid in Inkscape like this and then added text to it. I manually centered this one but I am wondering if there is a way to have it snap to the center through some of the alignment features? Basically I enabled gridlines, drew a square spanning 4 grids, and added the dashed lines across the middle. What I want is for the text to be at the intersection of the dashed lines. Is this possible other than manual work? I made this in Inkscape but solutions in other software also welcome!

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried the Align and Distribute panel?

Answer (score 3):

Use object snapping (whip crack sound).[image: snap to centers]

And here's another method.[image: snap to intersection]

For some reason text objects won't snap to a path intersection.  I don't know if this is an Inkscape bug or if it's intentional behaviour.  Snapping worked as expected when I grouped the text with a circle.  You can of course remove the circle fill and stroke to make it invisible.